# iMacros How to set any or a fix munber as start number then increase or decrease to a fix number?

Tags: imacros

In iMacros, I want to open 999.htm till 123.htm. I use !var but it seems like it's not working. After each loop the !var1 will be reset to 123, but I want !var1 to be 123.124.125.126 until 999.

Please see my code:

```
VERSION BUILD=9002379 
TAB T=1 
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS 
SET !VAR1 123
ADD !VAR1 1
URL GOTO=web.com/{{!VAR1}}.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this running it with run(loop) with 999 number of loops

```
VERSION BUILD=9002379 
TAB T=1 
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS 
SET !LOOP 123
URL GOTO=web.com/{{!LOOP}}.html
```

or

```
    VERSION BUILD=9002379 
    TAB T=1 
    TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS 
    SET !VAR1 999
    ADD !VAR -{{!LOOP}}
    URL GOTO=web.com/{{!VAR1}}.html
```

Comment: yeah! working! by the way how to start from 999.html decrease progressively to 123.html ? open 999.html then open 998.html then 997 996 untill 123.html ? THANK YOU friend!!